# Drag and Drop e Resize no Angular

Tags: angular

É possível combinar o recurso do drag and drop do Angular Material (cdkDrag) com redimensionamento?

Tentei utilizar o css, mas não funcionou, existe outra maneira?

Exemplo:

app.component.html

```html
<div class="drag-drop" cdkDrag>

Minha DIV

</div>
```

app.component.css

```css
.drag-drop{
  width:320px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background:#ccc;
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei a npm angular2-draggable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable#resizable), que me atendeu muito bem.